# Why is my delete operation for array elements not functioning properly?

Tags: arrays, c

I initialized an array and made some functions for performing operations such as traversing, inserting, deleting. Everything is working fine but the delete function is not giving the desired output. Rather than deleting the intended element it is deleting the last element. Please point out the mistake in my code because of which the delete operation is not getting executed properly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sizeofArray;
int atIndex;
int array[50];

void display(int array[], int elementsReq) //For traversing the array//
{
    if (elementsReq <= sizeofArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsReq; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough elements to display\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int insert(int array[], int elementToBeInserted, int atIndex, int sizeofArray) //For inserting elements//
{
    for (int i = sizeofArray - 1; i >= atIndex; i--)
    {
        array[i + 1] = array[i];
    }
    array[atIndex] = elementToBeInserted;
    return 1;
}

int delete (int array[], int sizeofArray, int atIndex) //For deleting elements//
{
    for (int i = atIndex; i < sizeofArray - 1; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int array[7] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};
    sizeofArray = 5;
    display(array, 5); //Displaying an Array//

    int elementToBeInserted = 3;
    int atIndex = 2;
    insert(array, 3, 2, 5); //Inserting an element//
    sizeofArray++;
    printf("NOW INSERTING THE MENTIONED ELEMENT\n");
    display(array, 6);
    if (insert(array, 3, 2, 5) == 1)
    {
        printf("ELEMENT INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ALAS!! ELEMENT NOT INSERTED\n");
    }

    printf("NOW DELETING...\n");
    delete(array, 6, 3);  //Trying to Delete the element at index no. 3//
    sizeofArray--;
    display(array, 5);
    if (delete (array, 6, 3) == 1)
    {
        printf("ELEMENT DELETED SUCCESSFULLY\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ALAS!! ELEMENT NOT DELETED\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `display` and `delete` in the wrong order

Comment: @Ultimate The array has the fixed number of elements equal to 5. In can not have 6 elements.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow According to the source the array has 7 elements.

Comment: Once your code will be fixed, I advise you to post it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), because it contains a good deal of of little inconsistencies: mixing global variables and variables passed to functions, poor functional encapsulation, may be others. You will receive their an extensive analysis of your code and nice advices on how to improve it and improve your programming skills.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Would definitely do that. Being a beginner I am always looking to improve. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `insert()` twice, so the `array` contains `{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 }` before deleting.

Check this by calling `display()` before.

*Note 1: You are also calling `delete()` twice.*

*Note 2: You might want to learn to debug small programs. You can use a debugger, and it's worth to learn that. Or you can insert more `printf()` at "strategic" places.*

Comment: As you advised after removing the "if statement block" for insert and delete functions  the code is fortunately running properly(As they were performing insert and delete twice). But my doubt is that why did using the insert function in an if statement's condition argument end up inserting the element rather than just executing the code inside the "if statement block"  ?

Comment: The condition of an `if` is _evaluated_ as an expression. This means that any function in this expression is called ("lazy evaluation" put aside).